# Btrfs: How do you clear the cumulative error counts that show up in 'btrfs device stats'?

Tags: btrfs

I caused some light data corruption on my array. I traced the problem down to bad hardware I swapped in by accident that immediately started acting up, that was involved in just a few writes.

Fortunately no data was lost. After replacing the known bad hardware and running a full scrub, Btrfs found redundant RAID-1 data for all three files involved (according to kern.log), which I later manually verified to be intact. SMART status on all the drives show no concerning issues - and like I said, I know what caused the corruption, the disks are fine, and that cause is gone.

But now when I do `sudo btrfs device stats /mnt/arr2`, by design it still shows those "permanently" accumulated error counts, whether they were repaired or not. And since they are irrelevant now in this case, I'd like to clear them - to make it easier to spot future actual HDD problems. Here's the list of my non-zero error tallies with that command:

```
[/dev/sdi].corruption_errs  281
[/dev/sdg].write_io_errs    16
[/dev/sdg].corruption_errs  265
[/dev/sdj].write_io_errs    54
[/dev/sdj].corruption_errs  768
```

ZFS has `zpool clear poolname`, though those counts are more ephemeral anyway. Does Btrfs have anything similar?

Man and doc pages, and google, are mum on it. I've seen one hint that `btrfs recover zero-log /mnt/arr2` might do the trick, but it was vague, and the intention of that specific command (according to official docs) goes far beyond that and seems like I would want to stay far away from it unless as a last resort to recover an array that won't mount.

**Is there such a command in Btrfs**? Thanks.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski, that did the trick! Funny that so many google searches didn't turn that up, until I included the magic word "reset". I had been using "clear", "zero", practically everything in the thesaurus except "reset". Thanks.

Comment: Good. You can write an answer then.

Answer (score 4):

As @KamilMaciorowski pointed out, the solution is:

`btrfs device stats --reset /mnt/your-array`

The `--reset` flag being the key.